# How to get images of Discogs releases?

Tags: image, discogs-api

I want to get images of Discogs releases. Can I do it without Discogs API?
They don't have links to the images in their db dumps.

Answer (score 6):

To do this without the API, you would have to load a web page and extract the image from the html **source code**. You can find the relevant page by loading `https://www.discogs.com/release/xxxx` where `xxxx` is the release number. Since html is just a text file, you can now extract the jpeg URL.

I don't know what your programming language is, but I'm sure it can handle String functions, like `indexOf` and `subString`. You could extract the html's `OG:Image` content for picture.

So taking an example: https://www.discogs.com/release/8140515

- Find the **`.indexOf("og:image\" content=\");`** save as `startPos` to some integer.
- That's 19 chars so next do a **`.indexOf(".jpg", startPos + 19);`** into a `endPos`.
   This gets the first occurence of **.jpg** after index of startPos + 19 any other chars.
- Now extract a **subString** from html text `img_URL = myHtmlStr.substring(startPos+19, endPos);`
- You should end up with a string reading like this below (extracted URL): 
  https://img.discogs.com/_zHBK73yJ5oON197YTDXM7JoBjA=/fit-in/600x600/filters:strip_icc():format(jpeg):mode_rgb():quality(90)/discogs-images/R-8140515-1460073064-5890.jpeg.jpg
- The process can be shortened to finding the **startPos** index of `https://img.`, then find first occurrence of `.jpg` when searching from after that **startPos** index. Extract within that length range. This is because the image URL is only mentioned in the html source at `https://img.`

Compare page at : https://www.discogs.com/release/8140515 with extracted URL image below.  

[image]

Comment: **note :** You might have to fine-tune those index Pos numbers. eg: You might change from **+19** to **+21** in order to cut off the quotation marks etc (**if needed** by your coding tool). You'll figure it out when testing...

Comment: Trying to fetch images of many releases, won't Discogs block automatic access?

Comment: @Collector, I don't think so (unless you can show otherwise). Access was not blocked for any of my testing AS3 code or PHP code. Each loaded 5 images just to check paths are parsed correctly.

Comment: Okay. The question was to get images without API. I believe I showed a good / correct answer for that. As for 5000 pics, that's a new detail. I'm not a server expert. I can only suggest you pace it out to fly under the radar, cos I can imagine 5000 requests from same IP address **at once** will look suspicious & be IP blocked. An "all day, everyday" site-user could access 5000 images spread over a week & wont be blocked so y'know... pace it out.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it with Java & [Jsoup](https://jsoup.org/) library.

- get HTML page of the release
- parse HTML & get `<meta property="og:image" content=".." />` to get `content` value

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class DiscogRelease {

    private final String url;

    public DiscogRelease(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        try {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(this.url).get();
            Elements metas = doc.head().select("meta[property=\"og:image\"]");
            if (!metas.isEmpty()) {
                Element element = metas.get(0);
                return element.attr("content");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DiscogRelease.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```